# Base64 encrypt - Not valid Base64 string

Tags: c#, base64

I have the following code

The problem is when I try to run it raises an exception and print this:

> entry is not a valid base64 string because it contains a character that is not base 64

This is the code:

```
    private static string Encrypt(string plainStr, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entro Encrypt");
        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        Console.WriteLine(completeEncodedKey);
        aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
        aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[1]);
        byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainStr);
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
        Console.WriteLine("Abajo de crypto");
        // The result of the encryption and decryption            
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
```

And this is the Stacktrace:

```
en System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)  
en cryptograph.Cryptography.Encrypt(String plainStr, String completeEncodedKey,
        Int32 keySize)  
en C:\programacion\cryptograph\cryptograph\cryptograph\Cryptography.cs:línea 65  
en cryptograph.Cryptography.generateKey(String key, String pass)  
en C:\programacion\cryptograph\cryptograph\cryptograph\Cryptography.cs:línea 13  
en cryptograph.cryptograph.Main(String[] args)  
en C:\programacion\cryptograph\cryptograph\cryptograph\cryptograph.cs:línea 21
```

Edit: completeEncodedKey is a random string, por example "AAAA" or something else. I understand that its lenght has to be a multiple of four

Comment: Well, it looks like `completeEncodedKey` isn't a valid base64 string. The rest of the code is kinda irrelevant without knowing the value of `completeEncodedKey` or why you believe it *should* be base64.

Comment: Some libraries add a new line '\n' character after 72 chars or so in the Base64 output. Not all Base64 implementation can digest that extra character while reading back. Check that no such character is being inserted in the output.

Comment: completeEncodedKey can be any string whose value is a multiple of four

Comment: There you have it, then. This is what Base64 is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: My client informs me that it works. It seems that I was passing the wrong values